# Find the maximum of $f(x,y,z) = xyz$, under the constraint $\frac1x +\frac1y + \frac1z = 1$

Tags: calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

> Find the maximum of $f(x,y,z) = xyz,$ under the following constraint:
>     $$\frac1x +\frac1y + \frac1z = 1$$ $x,y,z > 0$

I have attempted this question by using Lagrange multipliers and have only found the solution $x=y=z=3.$ However, it is clear that that this is a minimum value as the solution $x=2, y=z=4$ gives a greater value of $\,xyz.$ How, then, do I go about finding the maximum value?

Comment: Are the variables assumed to be positive?

Comment: Yes, for x,y,z > 0.

Comment: If $x=y=M$ then $z=\frac{1}{1-2/M}$ and $xyz=\frac{M^2}{1-2/M}$, which tends to $\infty$ as $M\to\infty$. Before searching for extrema, make sure that it exists.

Comment: I see that is a valid solution. However what if we were just looking for positive integer solutions? So is it fair to say that the maximum does not exist (since we have the problem of diving by 0 in the constraint)?

Comment: @TWPebble: There are (up to permutations) only three integer solutions, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/611420/42969.

Comment: Trouble with the Lagrange multipliers is it doesn't guaruntee that the optima are extrema for the constrained problem